# city ​autocomplete in django form

Tags: django, autocomplete

I have a city field and I need to autocomplete the city when I start typing without using the google maps api

```
<form action="{% url 'CityEvents' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
   <button type="submit">Choose</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Autocomplete has to fill in the missing letters from something, so if you do not want to use an API, you can collect all city names in the world 1 time, put in in a dictionary in your views, and then use a HTML datalist (with a for loop) to autocomplete the text. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist